Marginalising over N-dimensional multivariate Gaussian
I have a multivariate Gaussian with mean $\mu(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ and a covariance matrix $C$. In my case, the dimensions of the covariance matrix are $200 \times 200$. I have to marginalise over the $x = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ vector.
Is it possible to do that numerically? If so, can this numerical method be used to marginalise over any multivariate distribution (e.g. Student's - t) or products thereof?
Edit:
In particular, the integration I am interested in is
$$
\int P(\mathbf{\hat{a}}|\boldsymbol{\alpha})P(\mathbf{\hat{b}}|\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}))\boldsymbol{\alpha}^2 d\boldsymbol{\alpha} 
$$
which for the problem I'm attempting to solve is
$$
\propto \int \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{\hat{a}}-f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}))^\mathrm{T}C_1^{-1}(\mathbf{\hat{a}}-f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}))\right)}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{\hat{b}}-g(\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})))^\mathrm{T}C_2^{-1}(\mathbf{\hat{b}}-g(\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})))\right)}\boldsymbol{\alpha}^2d\boldsymbol{\alpha},
$$
where $P(\mathbf{\hat{a}}|\boldsymbol{\alpha})$ is a multivariate Gaussian with a diagonal covariance matrix $C_1$ and $P(\mathbf{\hat{b}}|\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is a multivariate Gaussian with a $200 \times 200$ covariance matrix $C_2$. So $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots\}$ is a vector of length $200$. $f$ and $g$ are functions of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, respectively.

Marginalization requires integration, so as long as you can numerically integrate then yes.

@lightxbulb I was asking how to do the integration over the vector μ={x1,x2,…} numerically.

Let $p(x,y)$ be a joint probability density function. Let $u, v \in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define $q(s,t) = p(su + tv)|\det[u, v]|$, Then the marginal distribution where we have integrated along $v$ should afaict be $r(s) =\int_{\mathbb{R}} q(s,t) ,dt$. You can use your favourite 1D numerical integration method on this.

Are you looking for the marginal distribution over some subset of the variables in the MVN vector or trying to compute some more complicated probability requiring integration over a region in n dimensions?

@BrianBorchers, thank you, I mean the latter, please see edit.

What do you mean by $\alpha^{2}$ when $\alpha$ is a vector?

@BrianBorchers Sorry, each element of the vector would be squared. So $$\alpha^2 = {\alpha_1^2, \ldots}$$.

Are $P(\hat{a}|\alpha)$ and $P(\hat{b}|\beta)$ supposed to be conditional probability densities? The notation looks like this would be the case, but I cannot make sense of it - on which variables are they conditioned, as far as I can tell both $\hat{a}$ and $\alpha$ are $n$-dimenional, where $n=200$. Is the integral vector-valued? What is its domain of integration? Is $d\alpha$ an $n$-dimebsional differential?

In general, iterated numerical integration in 200 dimensions is impractical.  You'd most likely want to use a Monte Carlo scheme.

@BrianBorchers Thank you. I was advised to use Monte Carlo, but don't know where to begin. Could you please provide a resource?

@lightxbulb Yes, those are conditional probabilities. $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\alpha$ are indeed n-dimensional. The differential is vector-valued, yes. The domain of integration is provided by the user, say from 0 to 0.1.

@Suyama87 If you can formalize this properly in your question I can try to provide an answer. By properly I mean specifying the integration domain, defining $P(\hat{a}|\alpha)$, $\alpha^2$, etc. Also note that ${\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots}$ would typically be understood as notation for a countably infinite set, and not a vector.

@lightxbulb Apologies for the lack of math, I was trying to be as generic as possible. Please see edit.

$\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$From the clarifications it seems that this is not a marginalization or conditional probability problem, instead you are integrating over some parameter that affects the mean of two normal distributions. I am also not sure whether $\bm{\alpha}^2$ is really a vector, or you meant the squared norm. In any case I will assume it is the vector formed by the Hadamard product $\bm{\alpha}\odot\bm{\alpha}$. Define the function:
\begin{align}
\bm{q}(\bm{\alpha}) &= \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{\hat{a}}-f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}))^\mathrm{T}C_1^{-1}(\mathbf{\hat{a}}-f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}))\right)}\\
&\cdot\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{\hat{b}}-g(\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})))^\mathrm{T}C_2^{-1}(\mathbf{\hat{b}}-g(\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})))\right)}\boldsymbol{\alpha}^2.
\end{align}
Then the integration problem reads:
\begin{equation}
\bm{I} = \int_{\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]} \bm{q}(\bm{\alpha})\,d\bm{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
To apply naive Monte Carlo you can then sample uniform random points $\bm{\alpha}_1,\ldots,\bm{\alpha}_N\in \prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]$ and compute:
\begin{equation}
\bm{I} \approx \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \bm{q}(\bm{\alpha}_k).
\end{equation}
More generally, if we pick $\bm{\alpha}_1,\ldots,\bm{\alpha}_N$ independent and identically distributed according to a density $r$, then the estimator becomes:
\begin{equation}
\bm{I} \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\bm{q}(\bm{\alpha}_k)}{r(\bm{\alpha}_k)}.
\end{equation}
In the uniform case $r(\bm{\alpha})$ is just equal to one divided by the volume of the domain.

Thank you! Three questions: a) n is the number of dimensions, such that n=200 and N is the number of random samples drawn? b) I am actually not sure about $\alpha^2$. In the 1-D case, it would be $\int f(\alpha)\alpha^2d\alpha$, and in fact $\alpha^2$ is a prior, so I am not sure how I could write a prior on the vector $\alpha$ in higher dimensions. Any ideas? c) I am experiencing underflows in one of the multivariate Gaussians. Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

$n$ is the number of dimensions yes, the integration domain doesn't have to be a hyperbox btw, $N$ is the number of samples. My only guess would be using $|\alpha|^2$ if you want a scalar-valued result, but this depends on your problem. I have no idea what you should do about the underflow issue.

@Suyama87 About your question (b): You have to determine what it is you want to do. You say it's a prior. That's a modeling problem where you are trying to encode something you know about the problem. What that is is something only you (or those who gave you the problem) can say. There is not universal answer any of us here can help you with.

You can use a completely flat prior over $\mathbb{R}^{200}$ if you use Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods since they only need an unnormalized density. 200 dimensions is pretty high for any MC method though so you may need to use a more sophisticated implementation
